# How can I tell TYPO3 to not Cache so it does update database values

Tags: database, caching, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I Created an Extension by using the Extension Builder, created a model, checked all standard actions and aggregated it to root. I installed the extension. I also selected a storage place. I included the static template, created a new page and put the frontend-plugin in and   So as far as I know very standard.

And when I started testing, it usually doesn't update old values if i create edit or delete them. Then I check the database, there is everything just fine and as i expect things to be. 
What always helps is clearing the frontend Cache and reload.

So how can I tell TYPO3 to not Cache this?

I am using TYPO3 6.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`config.no_cache` disables all caches, which makes your site really slow.

It's better to mark the controller actions as uncached when registering them in `ext_localconf.php`:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'Vendor.Extname',
    'Faq',
    array('Faq' => 'index,detail'),//available
    array('Faq' => 'index')//uncached
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
config.no_cache
```

For all caches